# How to apply similar rules to many cells in Excel 2016?

Tags: excel, formula

Disclaimer: I'm pretty novice at excel.

I have 2 rules:

If the dropdown cell = Used, then color itself and the 4 cells to the left yellow.

If the dropdown cell = Available, then color itself and the 4 cells to the left Green.

```
Rule                  Format                  Applies to 
=$G$5="Used"          Yellow Fill             =$C$5:$G$5
=$G$5="Available"     Green Fill              =$C$5:$G$5
```

[image: Rules]

[image: Cells]

**My question is: How can I apply these 2 rules to about 2000 other cells in the G column?**

ex:

```
Rule                  Format                  Applies to 
=$G$401="Used"          Yellow Fill           =$C$401:$G$401
=$G$401="Available"     Green Fill            =$C$401:$G$401
```

[image: Many Cells]

Comment: Change `$G:$5` to `$G$2000`

Comment: And get rid of the `$` in your formulas in front of the numbers. That's limiting it to just row 5. If you want this to go down 2000 rows, you need that to change as well.

Comment: Check out Scott's answer below, he can point you in the right direction. Just get rid of the $ in front of the number in the rule itself, and change the applies to to 2000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the Row in the formula to be relative:

```
=$G5="Used"
```

And the Applies to: to:

```
=$C$5:$G$2000
```

Do the same to the other formula and Applies To: range.

Comment: I might not have clarified this well, I want those 2 separate rules basically copied for each 2000 rows, When I did this change it doesn't affect the 4 cells to the left

Comment: yeah see edit I changed the Applies to:. @DylanGrove

Comment: Nope, it was my fault I had `=$G$5:$G$2000` and edited it to `=$C$5:$G$2000` later.